# What to use a 90 and when to two 45s in copper piping?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing

I'm replacing the tubing for an outdoor hose and in the wall I found what you see in the picture below. Why did they use two 45s and not one 90? Is there a general guideline for when to avoid 90s in favor of 2x45?

And what is that ugly coupling in the picture? It looks like they took a coupling and bent it into a 45. (To be it looks like they didn't have a 90 and improvised.)

[image]

Comment: Considering that someone soldered straight copper tubing onto the end of a threaded fitting instead of getting the proper male threaded to slip adapter, I wouldn't have much confidence in the other work this "plumber" did...

Comment: Also, this is garnering close votes for asking "when". If you get rid of that part and just ask about the mangled elbow, it'll likely stay open, though I'm not sure you'll get an actual answer.

Comment: @FreeMan It's very normal for a frost-free hose bibb like this one to support more than one connection style. The two most common combinations are 3/4" male thread on the outside with 1/2" female thread on the inside, or 1/2" male thread on the outside with sweat/solder connection on the inside. The faucet was probably designed to be installed exactly the way it's shown.

Comment: Well, #TIL, @GregHill. I just took the guess that the same "I'm in a hurry" thought process that led to using two 45° instead of one 90° since that's what was available, also led to soldering to the end of a threaded connection because there wasn't a matching threaded connector in the truck, either...

Answer (score 3):

When to use a pair of 45° versus one 90°? Most in the construction trades work according to these guiding principles:

- Use as few parts as possible, because handling more parts takes more time
- Get the job done with whatever I have on the truck, because trips to the supply house and back to the job site waste time

With that philosophy in mind one would use a pair of 45° elbows only if using a single 90° is impossible given building constraints, or if a 90° isn't on hand.

As for the mangled fitting: that's not a coupler. It's much too long; there's no way a person could bend a coupler without kinking/crimping it shut. This looks like a 45° elbow that has been twisted about half a turn. Perhaps the faucet was installed upside down and somebody, working from the outside and assuming that faucets are always connected with a threaded adapter, decided to just twist it around to fix the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

We can only speculate, and your guess makes sense. The usual reasons are:

- To effectively create a longer-radius bend to get around something
- To shorten the length of a run between pipes at right angles where space allows

Here we have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

> ...it looks like they didn't have a 90 and improvised...

Looks that way to me too. Ran out of 90s, didn't want to drive to the store.

There IS a concept of using a "sweep ell" instead of a sharp elbow in order to reduce the slight pressure drop that is created by the sharp turn, but that's generally insignificant in a residential system like this.